# "Failed to minify the code from this file" for an arrow function

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, arrow-functions

I have an ejected CRA/CRNA (React Native Web) application, and my `index.js` has the following lines:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('my_app', () => App);
```

which are basically copy/pasted from a guide. But webpack (when running `npm run build`, which calls CRA build.js script) emits an error on the 4th line, which contains an arrow function. If replaced with just `AppRegistry.registerComponent('my_app', App);`, which is correct syntax, but will cause a runtime error, it compiles just fine, which makes me think that there is a problem with arrow functions and webpack, despite the fact that my code uses arrow functions extensively, only the one in `index.js` causes an error. What gives?